# Sequelize belongsToMany association is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

My `workbook` is

```
Workbook = sequelize.define('Workbook', {
    isAssessment: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    },
    originalId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Workbook.belongsTo(models.Student);
        Workbook.belongsTo(models.Subject);
        return Workbook.belongsToMany(models.Question, {
          through: models.GradedWorkbook
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

I have another model:

```
GradedWorkbook = sequelize.define('GradedWorkbook', {}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      GradedWorkbook.belongsTo(models.Answer, {
        as: 'AnswerA'
      });
      GradedWorkbook.belongsTo(models.Answer, {
        as: 'AnswerB'
      });
      GradedWorkbook.belongsTo(models.Answer, {
        as: 'AnswerC'
      });
      GradedWorkbook.belongsTo(models.Answer, {
        as: 'AnswerD'
      });
      return GradedWorkbook.belongsTo(models.Answer, {
        as: 'AnswerSelected'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And the third model

```
Question = sequelize.define('Question', {
  active: {
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: false
  },
  flagged: {
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: false
  },
  questionText: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: true
  },
  level: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
  originalId: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Question.hasMany(models.Answer);
      Question.belongsTo(models.Instruction);
      Question.belongsTo(models.Topic);
      Question.belongsTo(models.Subject);
      Question.belongsTo(models.Passage);
      return Question.belongsToMany(models.Workbook, {
        through: models.GradedWorkbook
      });
    }
  }
});
```

When I try to do a query:

```
newWorkbook = {
  isAssessment: icmVal.isAssessment || false,
  originalId: icmSnapshot.key()
};

db.Workbook.findOrCreate({
  where: newWorkbook,
  include: [db.GradedWorkbook],
  defaults: newWorkbook
}).spread(function(dbWorkbook) {
  return console.log(dbWorkbook);
});
```

I get an error: `Unhandled rejection Error: GradedWorkbook is not associated to Workbook!`. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct association between Workbook and GradedWorkbook - it is only used as a through model. You can only use direct associations, e.g creating questions and workbooks together

```
Workbook.findOrCreate({
  include: [db.Question]
})
```

Comment: Hmmm. How do I get the information from GradedWorkbook then? Or add to it.

Comment: When you do e.g `Workbook.getQuestions()`, each question wil have an `GradedWorkbook` attribute with the infromation from the join table